# Implementing a function using python for string matching with equal number of times

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am trying to create a function that takes a string as parameter and return true if sub-string "bat" and "ball" appear same number of times.For ex: uegubatefheiball should return true as there is one instance of both appearing same number of times.

```
def sport_count(some_string):
    if (some_string.count(s1)>0):      
        print("true")  
    else:  
        print("false")
```

Answer (score 1):

You were already on the right track with using the strings `count` method. In this case, you would just count the "bat" and "ball" instances, and just do a simple compare.

```py
def sport_count(string):
    bat_count = string.count("bat")
    ball_count = string.count("ball")
    if bat_count == ball_count:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```